# How to create a form in django from the HTML source

Tags: python, django, html, templates, django-forms

I recently bought an HTML template to create my own website. Now I'm trying to port the step by step each HTML file that I need in my Django 1.7.1 app. So far everything works fine. After playing a little bit with it I decided to do some refactoring, in particular I'm interested to convert some part of the HTML sources into templates.

Let's take an example which represent the input for the username of the Sign Up form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Username</label>
    <div class="input-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        <input class="form-control placeholder-no-fix" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username" name="username"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

As I have seen from the Django documentation and from the examples and tutorials available online, one possible template could be the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">{{ placeholder }}</label>
<div class="input-icon">
    <i class={{ i_css_class }}></i>
    <input class="{{ css_class }}" type="{{ type }}" autocomplete="{{ autocomplete }}" placeholder="{{ placeholder }}" name="{{ name }}"/>
</div>
```

My questions are:

1. Is the template correctly written?
2. How do write the form?
3. How do write the view?

Aim:

- Finally, by using the django form I should get exactly the same HTML code as above.

Comment: Please add the Django View that is supplying the context shown in your HTML form.

Comment: @aron: actually the View doesn't do very much, just render the html file.

Answer (score 0):

1. No it's not correct you are missing the quotation marks, you should have something like:

   ```
   class="{{ css_class }}"
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   class={{ css_class }}
   ```
2. I suppose you are talking about the `Form` class: that part is not "mandatory" you can just have the form in plain html and do the validation in JS instead of using the Django facilites, however if you prefer to do it "the Django way" see here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/.
3. `HttpRequest.POST` is your friend in case you choose to do your own JS validation, otherwise if you do it "the Django way" you need to retrieve the data from `form.cleaned_data` as explained in the link I gave you above.

Comment: PS if you want to follow "the Django way" and still be able to write your own html for the form see the paragraph "Rendering fields manually" in the link I provided. This way you can still style the form according to your template without modifying your CSS